# How do I run an ubuntu container on windows?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm new to Docker and following through the Get started documentation, https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#explore-the-application-and-run-examples.

When I run 'docker run -it ubuntu bash' I get the following error:

> Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally latest: Pulling from
>   library/ubuntu C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: no matching manifest for
>   windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries. See 'C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

Here's additional docker information:

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:48:20 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 23:03:03 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

docker info

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 15063 (15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 31.92GiB
ID: ZVBR:TM24:KXS3:NF5Y:WJTD:7JR3:S4UB:TFIZ:7G32:EHIL:4TKD:RK3V
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 20
 System Time: 2017-09-28T10:05:53.8801328-07:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I'm a little confused why the OS/Arch version shows windows/amd64 while Architecture under info shows x86_64.

Any help with the error message would be great.

Comment: amd64 is the Linux name for the 64-bit x86 architecture, while x86_64 is the Windows (well, the Intel) name for it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Hong.

Comment: You might have to run the docker daemon with the `--experimental` flag.
`dockerd.exe --experimental`

Comment: I thought about that, although it's running as a windows service and docker info already is showing, Experimental: true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your issue is that your are using docker in Windows container mode and trying to pull a ubuntu image which is linux container image. You can't do that. You can run either windows containers or you can run linux containers.

You can switch to Linux container mode by right clicking on the docker tray icon as shown in below image

[image: Switch to Linux Containers]

Also `windows/amd64` and `x86_64` is both indicate 64bit OS and nothing else

Comment: That obviously fixed it and I learned a bit more about Docker, thank you. I was under the impression that this toggles the virtualization technology used but could run either windows or linux containers.

Comment: I was under same impression. If I run hello-world under linux containers the image size is in the kb; in windows containers it is a few hundred mb. Any explanation on that? Is it related? Is it possible if they wanted to to have images for both? My guess was that it was installing some hypervisor in windows containers. am I wrong?