# "docker pull redis" fails on Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, redis

I've installed Docker EE for Windows Server 2016 and was able to pull and run the hello-world example.

When I invoke "docker pull redis" , I get:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/redis
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

My docker versions:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-2
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   10e292d
 Built:        Thu Sep 21 19:58:53 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-2
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   777d4a1
 Built:        Thu Sep 21 20:08:05 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: When you're using `docker pull redis`, it's trying to pull from [official](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) redis repo which doesn't seem to have image built for your architecture. You should try [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/winamd64/redis/) [`docker pull winamd64/redis`] instead and see if it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run an ubuntu container on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474777/how-do-i-run-an-ubuntu-container-on-windows)

Comment: @Technext, that looks like it came from https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis which is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docker info shows, the server is not started in experiemental mode.

You need to start docker server with experiemental mode on windows server. Check [linux-containers-on-windows](https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/preview-linux-containers-on-windows/) to see how you can do that.